# I created a guessing game and I can't understand why my -= command function doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm a very new programmer(started less than a month ago). I really need some help with this.
Sorry if it's a bit long...
How this works is that my guesses go down every time I get something wrong(pretty obvious). Or it is supposed to, anyway.

This is a program I created as a prototype for a hangman project. Once I get this right, I'll be able to attempt the bigger project. Tell me if the full command above works differently for you or if you have any suggestion as to how to make it shorter or better or it's too early for me to attempt a project as big as this. Thank you!

```
import random

player_name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Good luck, " + player_name + "!")

words = ["program", "giraffe", "python", "lesson", "rainbows", "unicorns", "keys", "exercise"]
guess = " "
repeat = True

word = random.choice(words)
guesses = int(len(word))

while repeat is True:
    print("The word is " + str(len(word)) + " characters long.")
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
    if guess != word:
        guesses -= 1
        print("Incorrect")
        print("Try again")
    elif guess == word:
        print("Good job!")
        print(str.capitalize(word) + " is the right answer!")
        repeat = input("Do you want to play again? (input Yes/No)")
        if repeat == "Yes" or "yes":
            word = random.choice(words)
            repeat = True
        elif repeat == "No" or "no":
            print("Better luck next time!")
            repeat = False
        if guesses == 1:
            print("You only have one chance left.")
        if guesses <= 0:
            print("You lose...")
            repeat = input("Do you want to play again? (input Yes/No)")
            if repeat == "Yes" or "yes":
                repeat = True
            elif repeat == "No" or "no":
                print("Better luck next time!")
                repeat = False
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. What is the behavior you're seeing and how does it differ from what you're expecting?

Comment: guesses is only being checked if guess == word

Comment: `repeat == "Yes" or "yes":` and similar lines won't act as you're expecting though. Not sure if that's your problem here, but that should be `repeat == "Yes" or repeat == "yes":`

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the scope of your conditionals

```
while repeat is True:
    print("The word is " + str(len(word)) + " characters long.")
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
    if guess != word:
        guesses -= 1
        print("Incorrect")
        print("Try again")
    elif guess == word:
        print("Good job!")
        print(str.capitalize(word) + " is the right answer!")
        repeat = input("Do you want to play again? (input Yes/No)")
        if repeat == "Yes" or "yes":
            word = random.choice(words)
            repeat = True
        elif repeat == "No" or "no":
            print("Better luck next time!")
            repeat = False
    if guesses == 1:
        print("You only have one chance left.")
    if guesses <= 0:
        print("You lose...")
        repeat = input("Do you want to play again? (input Yes/No)")
        if repeat == "Yes" or "yes":
            repeat = True
        elif repeat == "No" or "no":
            print("Better luck next time!")
            repeat = False
```

this will fix the guesses issue, but you'll need to refactor the play-again logic.
Something like this

```
repeat = True
gameOver = False

while repeat is True:
    print("The word is " + str(len(word)) + " characters long.")
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
    if guess != word:
        guesses -= 1
        print("Incorrect")
        print("Try again")
    elif guess == word:
        print("Good job!")
        print(str.capitalize(word) + " is the right answer!")
        gameOver = True
    if guesses == 1:
        print("You only have one chance left.")
    if guesses <= 0:
        print("You lose...")
        gameOver = True

    if gameOver:
        playAgain = input("Do you want to play again? (input Yes/No)")
        if playAgain == "Yes" or "yes":
            word = random.choice(words)
            repeat = True
            gameOver = False
        elif repeat == "No" or "no":
            print("Better luck next time!")
            repeat = False
```